# How to find a sibling element's value using jQuery upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the value of the userid and password in the below HTML using the following jQuery code, but it doesn't return any value. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id='mainpane'>
    <form id='login' method='post' action='#'>
        <p>User Id:<input id='userid' type='text' name='userid'></input></p>
        <p>Password:<input id='password' type='text' name='password'></input></p>
        <p><input id='submit' type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'></input></p>           
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <p>Not a member? <a href="user-signup.html">Signup</a></p>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').delegate('input#submit','click',function(){
        alert('user id is: '+$(this).parent().parent().find('#userid').html());
        var request = $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/login",
            data: {userid:$('#userid').text(), password:$('#password').text}
            });

        });
```

The alert comes back with an empty data. Appreciate any pointers on what am I doing wrong.

Thanks, Kalyan.

Comment: made this fiddle so just chucking it in ayways: http://jsfiddle.net/tR3TY/1/

Comment: Those aren't sibling elements (they have different parents). But you don't need any DOM traversal `.parent()`, `.find()` or whatever methods because the elements you are trying to retrieve have ids and can just be selected directly with `$('#idhere')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.val()` to retrieve an input's value.

```
var userid = $("#userid").val();
var pass   = $("#password").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
$.post('/login', $('#login').serialize(), function() {});
```

in place of your `$.ajax` call :), the `.serialize()` takes all the form inputs' values and pass them to the server, encoded for you as well :)

Comment: This is Good! removed my answer! (note for questioner.)

Comment: -1 This is nice but doesn't answer the question. I don't understand the up vote either.

Comment: @iambriansreed sure, you are entitled to your opinion anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for this @nitfydude. Very helpful tip and this is what I was really trying to do - post form data.

Comment: @KumarM glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

You have quite a few issues so here's the corrected code with notes:

jQuery

```
$(function() {
// same as document.ready
    $('#login').submit(function(event){            
    // runs whenever the form is submitted - either enter or submit button is clicked
        event.PreventDefault();
        // since the form is submitted via ajax you wil want to keep the page from changing
        alert('user id is: '+$('#userid').val());
        // no need to reach back through the DOM with .parent() use the ID its the fastest, also you get input values with .val()
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/login",
            data: $('#login').serialize()
            // serialize() creates an object of all the form data based on the name attribute and values - very clean
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id='mainpane'>
    <form id='login' method='post' action=''>
        <p>User Id:<input id='userid' type='text' name='userid'/></p>
        <p>Password:<input id='password' type='text' name='password'/></p>
        <p><input id='submit' type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'/></p>           
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <p>Not a member? <a href="user-signup.html">Signup</a></p>
</div>
```

Inputs are self closing.

Answer (score -1):

you try this code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login').delegate('input#submit','click',function(){

            alert('user id is: '+$(this).parent().parent().find('#userid').val());
            var request = $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"/login",
                data: {userid:$('#userid').val(), password:$('#password').val()}
                });

            });
        });
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be nice if you explained what you've changed and why (rather than leaving it to the reader to compare your code with the original version).